# Put custom valued boxplots into the same frame

Tags: r

Let's say I have these data:

```
# (Please note these are statistical summaries, not actual data sets)
x1  = list(stats = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5)), n = 5)
x2  = list(stats = matrix(c(4,5,6,7,8)), n = 10)
x3  = list(stats = matrix(c(3,4,5,6,7)), n = 15)
x4  = list(stats = matrix(c(2,3,4,5,6)), n = 20)
x5  = list(stats = matrix(c(5,6,7,8,9)), n = 25)

xx1 = list(stats = matrix(c(1.5,2,3,4,4.5)), n = 5)
xx2 = list(stats = matrix(c(4.5,5,6,7,7.5)), n = 10)
xx3 = list(stats = matrix(c(3.5,4,5,6,6.5)), n = 15)
xx4 = list(stats = matrix(c(2.5,3,4,5,5.5)), n = 20)
xx5 = list(stats = matrix(c(5.5,6,7,8,8.5)), n = 25)
```

I wish to plot these boxplots using my own statistical summaries like so:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,5))
bxp(x1, ylim = c(0,10))
bxp(x2, ylim = c(0,10))
bxp(x3, ylim = c(0,10))
bxp(x4, ylim = c(0,10))
bxp(x5, ylim = c(0,10))

bxp(xx1, ylim = c(0,10))
bxp(xx2, ylim = c(0,10))
bxp(xx3, ylim = c(0,10))
bxp(xx4, ylim = c(0,10))
bxp(xx5, ylim = c(0,10))
```

Here's what I get:
[lots-of-boxplots.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9aSy.jpg)
[image]
Questions:

1) Currently, each plot has its own y-axis. How do I make it such that each **row** has its own axis?

2) How do I give the overall image 2 y-axis labels by labelling the top row as "x values" and the bottom row as "xx values"?

3) How do I give the overall image 5 x-axis labels by labelling the first column as "Group 1", the second column as "Group 2", and so on?

Comment: If they are sharing the same yaxis, why not plot all of them as one boxplot?

Comment: Well, if I did a boxplot(y~x) style plot, it would give me statistical summaries irrelevant to my needs (i.e. quartiles, medians and ranges). What I would like is the boxplots to show standard errors or variances hence why I cannot use boxplot(). Instead, using bxp(), I'm unsure how to "plot all of them as one boxplot" due to the limitations of the z argument in bxp(). I'm quite new to R so the answer may be very obvious and simply has eluded me!

Comment: Try `x <- boxplot(mtcars$mpg~mtcars$cyl)`, x will be a list object we can pass to as `bxp(x)`. Using custom values, we can construct the same list object and pass it to `bxp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got quite a little mess here

```
# (Please note these are statistical summaries, not actual data sets)
x1  = list(stats = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5)), n = 5)
x2  = list(stats = matrix(c(4,5,6,7,8)), n = 10)
x3  = list(stats = matrix(c(3,4,5,6,7)), n = 15)
x4  = list(stats = matrix(c(2,3,4,5,6)), n = 20)
x5  = list(stats = matrix(c(5,6,7,8,9)), n = 25)

xx1 = list(stats = matrix(c(1.5,2,3,4,4.5)), n = 5)
xx2 = list(stats = matrix(c(4.5,5,6,7,7.5)), n = 10)
xx3 = list(stats = matrix(c(3.5,4,5,6,6.5)), n = 15)
xx4 = list(stats = matrix(c(2.5,3,4,5,5.5)), n = 20)
xx5 = list(stats = matrix(c(5.5,6,7,8,8.5)), n = 25)


## gather up the data
ll <- mget(ls(pattern = '^x\\d'))
l1 <- list(stats = do.call('cbind', lapply(ll, '[[', 1)),
           n = unlist(lapply(ll, '[[', 2)))

ll <- mget(ls(pattern = 'xx\\d'))
l2 <- list(stats = do.call('cbind', lapply(ll, '[[', 1)),
           n = unlist(lapply(ll, '[[', 2)))

## plot
par(mfrow = c(2, 1), mar = c(2,5,1,1))
bxp(l1, ylab = 'x values', xaxt = 'n')

par(mar = c(2,5,0,1)) ## keep space for group labels
bxp(l2, ylab = 'xx values', xaxt = 'n')
mtext(at = 1:5, side = 1, text = paste('Group', 1:5), line = .5)
```

[image]